# Articles not showing in joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I am trying to use joomla with the yoo catalyst theme. And i was trying to have an article on my page. But the problem is that article is not showing in my theme. But when i choose default theme it is showing the accurate results. Is there any setting that i am missing with this theme?

Please Help.

Comment: Yootheme templates aren't any different to standard templates apart from more flexibility, module positions, features etc. So you created a menu item and assigned an article to it, am I right?

Comment: yes, i have done that in the similar way. But didn't get any results.

Comment: can you provide a link to your website and check if the error log is showing anything?

Comment: http://www.2ademo.com/MedFit2.5/index.php?option=com_helloworld&view=helloworld

Answer (score 0):

Think the answer if fairly simple. The link your provided:

http://www.2ademo.com/MedFit2.5/index.php?option=com_helloworld&view=helloworld

is to a dummy component, hence the **"option=com_helloworld&view=helloworld"** and not to an actual article. When I went on to the website, I clicked on the "Privacy Policy" link which directed me to the following page:

http://www.2ademo.com/MedFit2.5/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=56&Itemid=106

and the article is showing fine on here

Comment: Yes i know. But now i am adding the new articles to it using the views. But it is not working today. And this page is the new article page.

Comment: if you click there on members>myaccount>change my password then it will be the same link i provided and it shows a blank screen to me.

Answer (score 0):

@user1929236 This is not an actual problem, it was actually caused by template configuration.
Since you have set hidden content on homepage in the template config, the content in the url was also hidden (an url without itemid will use the same template profile with homepage).